# Calculating overall variability over multiple datasets

Tags: standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics

I am trying to determine a way to measure the consistency of transit hours performed by transportation providers over their entire portfolio of shipping routes.

For example, if a company has 3 routes, what would be the best way to show the standard deviation as one single number? I have multiple providers that I would like to evaluate, and they have between 1 and 50 or so routes a piece, each of varying mean transit hours.

```
Ex: (provider #1) 
Route 1: Count 1120, Mean Hours = 35, Standard deviation = 18
Route 2: Count 654, Mean Hours = 71, Standard deviation = 23 
Route 3: Count 802, Mean Hours = 286, Standard deviation = 32
```

Please let me know if there is any additional information I could share to make this more clear.

Comment: Why not give a (perhaps weighted) average of the corresponding standarad deviations?

Comment: @YairDaon -- I was thinking the same thing, and I'm also thinking that could constitute an answer.

James -- do you just need a number, or are you expected to also conduct statistical analysis on that number?

Comment: It comes down to what "consistency" means for customers. The standard deviations themselves may be misleading: many customers could be ready to tolerate a variation of 32 hours in a 286 hour trip, but not in a 35 hour trip, for instance. This shows that any useful, objective answer to your question really needs more information about how consistency relates to the company's business objectives.

Comment: I just need a number as a reference to rank the several competing providers. Lowest variability is most favorable etc..

Comment: So a weighted average would show 23.63 (rounded) for this example dataset, would you agree?

Comment: Whuber - I agree. to address that I was contemplating using something like relative standard deviation to obtain deviation as  a percent of the mean. just wanted to start off with a more basic questions so I don't get too confused before moving forward with something slightly more complicated.